# Convert file to dictionary and use specific key's value as an variable

Tags: python

I would need to know what is the most simplest way to convert file with unknown keys and values (format could be txt) into dictionary(or list) and for example first key's value into variable which could further used to make some calculation with rest of the values. My incorrect code below :

```
file = input("Insert name of the file.")
    try:
        disc = open(file, 'r')
        my_dictionary = {}
        for line in disc:
            k,v  = line.rstrip().split() #in case of empty rows in file and 
            my_dictionary [k]= int(v) #  spaces between keys and values
        amount_k = len(my_dictionary) # lenght of dict
        first_value = my_dictionary.item(1)
        i=1
        for sub in my_dictionary:
           my_dictionary[sub] = my_dictionary[sub]/((1/i)*first_value*amount_k)
           i += 1
     except OSError:
           print("the" , file ,"could not be read")
```

I guess variable first_value is incorrect and the reason why my code above does not work properly or at all (Traceback: first_value = my_dictionary.item(1)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'item')? To recall I would like know how to convert value into variable and should I use list or like instead of dictionary in cases like this (pros and cons if any)? 
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with *unknown file*? What is the *format* of the file?

Comment: Where's your `except` block?

Comment: Please add your traceback.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience! Txt could be the format of the file.

Comment: Please put code in the question, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

The first item should be `my_dictionary.items()[0]`

See the `items` method [doc](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).